# Implementing a process with JPA for Activiti 5.9

Tags: spring, jpa, activiti

how can we write Spring bean with JPA logic in activiti 5.9 using oracle as back end

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this answers your question but I'll give it a try.
You don't need to do something special to achieve your goal.
Declare you processEngine as a Spring bean, you can find information about that at [Activiti user guide](http://www.activiti.org/userguide/#N10689):

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

  <bean id="processEngineConfiguration" class="org.activiti.engine.impl.cfg.StandaloneProcessEngineConfiguration">

    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:h2:mem:activiti;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=1000" />
    <property name="jdbcDriver" value="org.h2.Driver" />
    <property name="jdbcUsername" value="sa" />
    <property name="jdbcPassword" value="" />

    <property name="databaseSchemaUpdate" value="true" />

    <property name="jobExecutorActivate" value="false" />

    <property name="mailServerHost" value="mail.my-corp.com" /> 
    <property name="mailServerPort" value="5025" />    
  </bean>

</beans>
```

After that you implement your Spring bean including JPA logic. There is nothing Activiti specific here, you just implement it like there is no Activiti. You can find details at [this site](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Spring). Finally you can use this bean in your [Service Tasks](http://www.activiti.org/userguide/#bpmnJavaServiceTask) by that method:

```
<serviceTask id="javaService" 
         name="My Java Service Task" 
         activiti:expression="#{printer.printMessage(myVar1, myVar2)}" />
```

Here, `printer` can be your Spring bean or just a named variable in your process context. Variables `myVar1` and `myVar2` are variables residing in your process context.

You can also design your JPA-logic-including-bean as an Activiti aware one by that:

```
 <serviceTask id="serviceTask" activiti:delegateExpression="${delegateExpressionBean}" />
```

In this case, `delegateExpressionBean` is your JPA-logic-including-bean, but class of that bean must implement Activiti's `JavaDelegate` interface.
It is your choice.